# Почему эффект не отображается на канвасе

Tags: unity3d, эффекты, particles

Почему эффект не отображается на канвасе, а отображается в поле видимости камеры[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

У `Canvas` для экономичности, своя система рендеринга. Он отрисовывает каждый `Canvas` отдельно, только по факту изменения элемента в нем, а не каждый кадр. Он рендерит только элементы `UI`. Для отображения других объектов, например 3d модели используется `RawImage`, желательно находящихся на отдельном `Canvas` соответствующих размеров.

Ну и ваш `LineRenderer` с `ParticleSystem` тупо не находятся на `Canvas`.